# YAML: mixing inline with regular map for same object

Tags: yaml

Is it possible to mix an inline (json-like) map with regular map definitions for the same object?

Consider the following example:

```
person: {age: 32, weight: 82}
  name: foo
```

The resulting person should have the given age, weight, and name.

EDIT: moved my solution to an answer

Comment: Good solution. Note that it is encouraged to give an answer to your own question. You might as well post your solution as an answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible by using the merge tag:

```
person: 
  <<: {age: 32, weight: 82}
  name: foo
```

That yields:

```
{
  "person": {
    "age": 32, 
    "name": "foo", 
    "weight": 82
  }
}
```